# Chroot directory limit user to sftp folder

Tags: chroot

My current setup which works:
sshd_config file:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group filetransfer2
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Linux commands I ran:

```
addgroup --system filetransfer
usermod -G filetransfer username
chown root:root /home/username
chmod 755 /home/username
cd /home/username
mkdir docs public_html
chown username:filetransfer *
```

And the username is restricted to /home/username folder and works perfectly.
Now what i try to do is limit username to: `/home/somefolder/public/domain.com/`

When I use `sudo usermod --home username /home/somefolder/public/domain.com/` it changes the default directory of username when logged in with sftp. Although it refuses to login. I've also tried all the above steps while using `/home/somefolder/public/domain.com/` without luck, it refuses to login sftp.

I have to give some support desk my sftp login and obviously I don't want to give them my root login details and therefor want to limit them to the domain.com folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a chroot to work properly as you did earlier, you have to force root to be owner of the directory and all files/directories inside that directory may be owned by the user.

For your requirement to work you need to create separate directory trees. For example:
For User1: /srv/www/user1/
For User2: /srv/www/user2/

In the above example, you will force root to be owner of /srv/www/user1 & /srv/www/user2 and then individually make both users owner of everything inside ~/user1/* & ~/user2/*.

This is what you have done earlier but now if you need multiple users with chroot jail configuration, then you would be required to give separate trees under forced root owned directory.

Hope this help!